# Проблема со вставками ассемблера в коде C++

Tags: c++, циклы, ассемблер

У меня есть задание: нужно написать код, который выполняет выражение 2x[i]-y[i]+1 и результат записывается в массив z. Программу нужно написать на C++ с ассемблерными вставками, причем на C++ реализовать просто инициализацию, заполнение и вывод массивов, а на ассемблере уже вычисления. Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что на ассемблере результат моих вычислений не записывается результат. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем дело?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int x[4];
        int y[4];
        int z[4];
        cout << "Enter X elements: ";
        cin >> x[0] >> x[1] >> x[2] >> x[3];
        cout << "Enter Y elements: ";
        cin >> y[0] >> y[1] >> y[2] >> y[3];
        __asm{
            mov cx, 3
            mov esi, 0
            L1:
            mov ebx, x[esi]
            add ebx, x[esi]
            sub ebx, y[esi]
            inc ebx
            mov z[esi], ebx
            inc esi
            loop L1
        }
        cout << z[0] << z[1] << z[2] << z[3] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Какие ошибки у вас? Какой компилятор?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибки в вашем коде - надо использовать не `cx`, а `ecx`, и давать ему значение не 3, а 4. И в индексах использовать не `[esi]`, а `[esi*4]` - это индексы в С++ знают о размерах элементов массива :), а у вас - ассемблер...

Словом, я бы вычислял так (VC++):

```
__asm {

    mov ecx,4
Cycle:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR x[ecx*4-4]
    shl     eax, 1
    sub     eax, DWORD PTR y[ecx*4-4]
    inc     eax
    mov     DWORD PTR z[ecx*4-4],eax
    loop    Cycle
}
```

Comment: Храни тебя господь